# order the array in specific order

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays

I have a array and want to sort the array in specific order

```js
var orderedObj = {
  "1st Presentation / Meeting": 0,
  "Follow-On Meetings": 1,
  "Hold\/Uncategorized": 2,
  "MGL": 3,
  "PGL": 4,
  "BGL": 5,
  "RGL": 6,
  "SGL": 7,
  "Uncategorized Leads": 8,
  "Identified Opportunities": 9,
  "QO under evaluation": 10
};

const typobj = ["Uncategorized lead", "Hold/Uncategorized", "RGL", "PGL", "MGL", "QO under evaluation", "Reaches", "Identified Opportunities", "BGL", "Back to marketing", "SGL", "Follow-On Meetings", "1st Presentation / Meeting"];

var typesOrd = typobj.sort((a, b) => orderedObj[a.label] - orderedObj[b.label]);
console.log(typesOrd);
```

Not able to sort in order getting output as `["Uncategorized lead", "Hold/Uncategorized", "RGL", "PGL", "MGL", "QO under evaluation", "Reaches", "Identified Opportunities", "BGL", "Back to marketing", "SGL", "Follow-On Meetings", "1st Presentation / Meeting"]`

Comment: Does it really necessary, i dont re order objects that much,

Comment: maybe I can save the order in array or json

Comment: Remove the `label` part. `a` is the individual array item. Just `orderedObj[a]` gives you the priority value for each item

Comment: I have made you an answer @user3386779

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the values directly and have an eye on spelling.

Sorting sorts the given array.

Mabe you start the values of the order object with one instead of zero and use a default value for sorting unknown value to the wanted position.

```js
var orderedObj = {
  "1st Presentation / Meeting": 0,
  "Follow-On Meetings": 1,
  "Hold\/Uncategorized": 2,
  "MGL": 3,
  "PGL": 4,
  "BGL": 5,
  "RGL": 6,
  "SGL": 7,
  "Uncategorized Leads": 8,
  "Identified Opportunities": 9,
  "QO under evaluation": 10
};
const typobj = ["Uncategorized Leads", "Hold/Uncategorized", "RGL", "PGL", "MGL", "QO under evaluation", "Reaches", "Identified Opportunities", "BGL", "Back to marketing", "SGL", "Follow-On Meetings", "1st Presentation / Meeting"];

typobj.sort((a, b) => orderedObj[a] - orderedObj[b]);

console.log(typobj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This code below.

```js
// RAW
var orderedObj = {
  "1st Presentation / Meeting": 0,
  "Follow-On Meetings": 1,
  "Hold\/Uncategorized": 2,
  "MGL": 3,
  "PGL": 4,
  "BGL": 5,
  "RGL": 6,
  "SGL": 7,
  "Uncategorized Leads": 8,
  "Identified Opportunities": 9,
  "QO under evaluation": 10
};
//Target order
const typobj = ["Uncategorized Leads", "Hold/Uncategorized", "RGL", "PGL", "MGL", "QO under evaluation", "Reaches", "Identified Opportunities", "BGL", "Back to marketing", "SGL", "Follow-On Meetings", "1st Presentation / Meeting"];

var new_obb={};
typobj.forEach(function(item){
new_obb[item]=orderedObj[item];
});

// Final Output
console.log(new_obb);
```